# Animations - problem with multiple actions

Tags: animation, .fbx, actions, transform-orientation

I work as AR Developer on various software and Hololens 2 from Microsoft. I have an assembly created in Creo which I've exported to OBJ with groups containing particular parts so I can move them in Blender separately. I want to create animations in single FBX file, and those animations will appear on Hololens from dropdown menu. I want to do it that way to show how to perform repair process of big industry machine. I know that I can do it by creating one Action in Action Editor for each step. But when I create an Action in which I rotate one part, I want to create another Action, I select different part in model and its drifting away to strange localization. I assume it is changing it's translation points or something
Is there any option to do it different way? What am I doing wrong? Maybe the Action is applied to one model at the time and selecting another model is translating it to this previous one?
But how to do it to still be able to export particular animations in one FBX file?